# Reason behind the train remaining intact to the Train track

Tags: homework-and-exercises, experimental-physics

I was wondering why trains moving at such hard speeds remain intact to the railway track even while turning. Is it because of friction ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=agd8B-31bjE

Comment: @lemon While that video is interesting, it explains how the train wheels spin at different speeds in a turn (train differentials), as compared to how the train manage to stay on the track and not derail while travelling at high speeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Friction is a force that does not act normal to the surface, but rather perpendicular to the surface. Trains do not derail when travelling on high speeds across turns simply because the train tracks are slightly inclined.